# Can I split items from list of strings using streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am writng a simple javaFX program where I get user name and password from a file, and compare it to the user name and password that the end-user entered.
I was able to achieve this with this code:

```
        Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file));
        lines = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(String item : lines){
        String[] itemSplitted = item.split("=");
        switch(itemSplitted[0].trim()){
            case "User name":
                if (itemSplitted[1].trim().equals(userName))
                    counter++;
                break;
            case "Password":
                if (itemSplitted[1].trim().equals(password))
                    counter++;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 2)
        System.out.println("details are correct!!");
    else throw new RuntimeException("Details are not correct!");
```

How can I achieve the same result using streams and lambdas?
Thanks

Comment: You have only two elements, username & password. And they are very different. It does not make sense to use a stream IMO;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use streams, but the biggest improvement I guess comes from transforming the stream of lines into something more usable:

```
void login(String file, String userName, String password) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
        .map(line -> line.split("=", 2))
        .filter(array -> array.length == 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                array -> array[0].trim(),
                array -> array[1].trim()));
    if (map.get("User name").equals(userName)
            && map.get("Password").equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("details are correct!!");
    } else throw new RuntimeException("Details are not correct!");
}
```

You could technically use filter() and only keep correct password/user lines, then count the elements in the stream but that would look pretty ugly IMO.

```
long count = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
    .map(line -> line.split("=", 2))
    .filter(array -> array.length == 2)
    .filter(array -> 
          (array[0].trim().equals("User name") && array[1].trim().equals(userName))
       || (array[0].trim().equals("Password")  && array[1].trim().equals(password))
    )
    .count();
if (count == 2) ...
```

This is also more error prone, since a file like

```
User name=root
User name=root
```

would allow any password. The same issue exists in your code too.

Comment: When you use `line.split("=", 2)`, you don’t need a subsequent `.filter(array -> array.length==2)` and may even support `=` as valid password character.

Comment: @Holger good point for `=` in passwords, but the filter also skips lines without a `=` iow for `length=1`